# Java Memory Model applicable to actions and not statements

Tags: multithreading, volatile, java-memory-model, happens-before

I got this from blog of A. Shipilev that JMM is applicable to actions and not statements with undermentioned code and statement

> …​they say that g = 1 happens-before int lg = g. This train-wrecks the reasoning further by logically arriving at conclusion int lx = x would always see x = 1 (since x = 1 hb g = 1, and int lg = g hb int lx = x too). This is a very easy mistake to make, and you have to keep in mind that happens-before (and other orders in JMM formalism) is applied to actions, not the statements.

https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#pitfall-volatiles-wrong

I was under the impression that both are same. Is there any underlying difference that I am missing.

```
int x;
volatile int g;

void m() {
  x = 1;
  g = 1;
}

void r() {
  int lg = g;
  int lx = x;
}
```

Comment: It is as explained in blog.. nothing more to add here.. similar subject you may find on stackoverflow as well..

Comment: @muradm the diff between action vis-a-vis statement as applied in JMM context in the blog was not apparent to me hence the query.

Comment: your question is not articulated, not clear, what kind of problem does it makes? Author in the next paragraph explains the difference between statement and action. It is well known fact that roughly any program is not being executed as it is written (stated), but executed interpreted (with actions) by CPU, JMM whatever. Author states this fact and consequences.